# Eclipse shortcut to change panel size

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, shortcut

I was wondering if there was a shortcut in Eclipse to change the view height/width.

Normally you have to find the line where your cursor change to a vertical/horizontal two-sided arrow, click and then drag to change the panel height/width.

Is there a shortcut where you just press, for example <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> or the mouse wheel, and just move the cursor around and the current panel (the one under your mouse) change size accordingly ? Or a plugin for this ? This would be a lot faster (even though it's not that terrible).

Either I didn't find the way to put it clearly or nobody asked this because I didn't find anything, only stuff about switching views/panels from one to another or changing font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such shortcut. Providing a plug-in therefore seems difficult as there is no API to query or set the size of a view stack.

The only shortcut related to changing the size of a view stack is <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>. It maximizes/minimizes the view stack of the currently active view.